# Swift • Can Enums have too many Cases?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, enums, switch-statement

I am working on a Swift App which uses an `Enum`. However, this Enum will have a bunch of cases. Maybe 1,000 or even more.

**Code**

```swift
enum Name: Int, CaseIterable {
    case name1
    case name2
    case name3
    // Many more...
    
    var string: String {
        switch self {
            case name1: return "Name 1"
            case name2: return "Name 2"
            case name3: return "Name 3"
            // Many more...
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:** Will an Enum with more than 1,000 Cases work? Or will there be a problem? Which other Data Structure is the best fit in this case?

**Question 2:** the Enum has also computed Properties with Switch-Statements in it. Is there any Problem with Switch-Statements with over 1,000 Cases?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Please provide more context - the types of cases/data you need to make it work with. Without more information, it is not clear what you want to do with this.

Comment: @TarunTyagi Its just an Enumeration of different medications, nothing special It also contains some computed Properties with switch-statements inside it.

Comment: You usually use an enum for a finite number of elements that belongs to the same group. Medications to me is more of an infinite (growing) collection so maybe an array, dictionary or set would be a better fit. Even if this group is finite I think 1000 would be way to many and give you code that is hard to understand and maintain. You could of course divide them into smaller groups with an enum for each group.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks for your detailed answer. Actually, the number of names is huge but finite. The user is not able to add or delete names. Your right, that an enum of 1,000 cases is hard to read, however a List or Dictionary with 1,000 elements is not easier to read either?

Comment: 1000 elements is going to be a nightmare to maintain. How are you getting the values? Are you typing them in, getting them from a network call. There are ways to deal with large numbers of items, including having their own properties, but sticking them all in an enum is probably the wrong approach.

Comment: @Abizern I got a huge Excel-Table that contains the Data. The idea was to generate the Enum using a short Script or something like this.

Comment: If you are including the data at compile time, then you would probably be better of using something like Core Data or Realm to store the data and convert populate it with the contents of your Excel file. Either of these persistence mechanisms will allow you to get data from each item in a much better way than a huge enum.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this -

1. Store the known list of valid names in a json resource file.
2. Add a failable initializer on your data model that validates the name value against this known list of names from that json. If you provide an invalid name value (that's not known in names json) - init will fail and your data model will not be instantiated.
3. Data model's name property is still a `String` - not an enum case.